# JavaFX correct way to open and close a Stage multiple times

Tags: javafx, stage, fxmlloader

**Problem:**
I am working on a client server desktop application using JavaFx, everything works fine except that I have found that when I open a new stage clicking a button on the Home Page, the new Stage loads data only the first time I open it. The initialize method of the new stage sends a request to server and receives back an object whose fields are loaded on the new stage. None exception is thrown, the server always send the object correctly (tested by printing its vales on console).

My suspicion is that when I click the button to open a new stage, it creates a new instance of the FXML Loader each time. What I don't get is dued to the fact that the execution cycle is always the same both the first time I open the stage and the following ones.

I finally tried to insert a button in the second window which, when clicked, loads the object on the window, and this works correctly also when I open the window multiple times, but obviously I don't like this solution, which would force the user to click the button to retreive data.

Here is the HomePage Controller method that allows to open the new stage:

```
@FXML
void showSecondView(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {


               
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

                loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/View_FXML/generaRichiesta.fxml"));
                Pane secondPageLayout = loader.load();
                SecondController secCon = loader.getController();
             

                stage = new Stage();
                stage.setScene(new Scene(secondPageLayout));

             
                stage.setTitle("Second Stage");


                stage.show();

}
```

Here is the Initialize method for the Second Stage

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
                         
        //sending request to server and calling the following function to update the
        //view withe the received object
        
       Platform.runLater(
            () -> {
               //setting the view node "textField" with the object received from server
               //if I print this value on console I always get the object correctly but
               //it is loaded only the first time. When i call this function from a button it always
               //works but I should do it manually
               textField.setText().receivedObject.toString(); 
              
            }
        );
}
```

I really don't get what the problem could be, I think it may be because when  I create every time and FXMLLoader object.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: same procedure as always: [mcve] required ;)

Comment: Hi, i know that it'd be bettere to produce a reproducibile example, but right now I'm quite through the application so I should make a little prototype to make it work. I'm really struggling with this bug and it's quite hard to find what doesn't work since it doesn't throw any error. I see from your profile that Java desktop application is you business. I ask if we may get in touch maybe privately to can show you the problem. 
I apologize if I seemed intrusive.Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Make sure you aren't swallowing them anywhere (including a failed e.g. `Task` without the necessary code to report the error). Have you added any (possibly temporary) logging statements to make sure the code you think should be executing is actually executing? Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see exactly what goes wrong and where?

Comment: Yes sure, I logged and debugged both controllers and the cycle between every statements is always the same... That's what is driving me crazy... I'll try to debug the client server cycle too even if the logger already tell me that the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, basically I'm using the Observable Pattern, every time I opened a controller, I associated the controller object in a hashmap and didn't accept other insertion of objects of the same class. Also each time I closed the second stage, I omitted to remove to remove the first instance of the controllere from the map, so the Observable Pattern sent notifications of changes only and always to the first instance of the controller created and not to the subsequent ones that were created by reopening the window